# Spring boot to allow any content type in headers for GET request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the following error because client is sending content-type as multipart/form-data and my controller method is GET.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Is there a way in spring boot which will allow the controller to accept any content type in header?

```
@GetMapping("/logic")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> appLogic(){
//application logic 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is your URI is `/content-type`? Is this on purpose? If it is it is confusing. "content-type" is a headser for HTTP request and Response. In Request this header tells server-side what is actual type of data sent in request body. Since method `GET` does not allow request body this header for `GET` request is meaningless. your error tells you that request notified server (through setting header `content-type` to value `multipart/form-data`) that request body will be of type `multipart/form-data`, but request didn't contain any such data, and could not have contained it since `GET` can not have a body. If you need to pass some info in request body you will need to use method `POST` or `PUT`

Comment: I kept the url for testing. Updated the url. Is there a way like GET can ignore whatever content-type in header?

Comment: @TomJava I don't know if you can make method GET too ignore meaningless  "content-type" header. I don't think so, but don't know for sure. In any case the best practice would be not to send a header that has no value and as you can see can harm your functionality.